# Make member only accessible through property even in owner class?

Tags: c#, properties, visibility, member

Let's see this code snippet:

```
class A {
    int m_x;
    public int x {
        get { return m_x; }
        set { ... }
    }
}
```

`m_x` is private so it's accessible in class A, but other classes can only access it through the public `x` property.

I have methods which *MUST* be called everytime x is changed. (it's in `set { ... }`)

My problem is that in **class A** I can change the value of `m_x` directly.

- This way the *'MUST be called'* methods aren't called.

Currently the only indicator for this error is that `m_` prefix.

**Is there a way to make a compile-time checking?**

Comment: But if is a private field, that it can be changed only by *your* code, which you can control, right?

Comment: Yes, but there is the human error factor. If in one of my tired moments I write m_x instead of x I will have to look for the source of the bug for hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to make a compile-time checking?

No, class `A` is supposed to know that it has to call the method each time the private field is set. This is part of the internal logic that the class actually implements.

The compiler cannot stop you from setting a private field without calling a method first. This will be the responsibility of the developer of the class and not the compiler.